# Conditional formatting in Excel using VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am extremely new to VBA world and need some assistance with the VBA side of conditional formatting.

1. I need conditional formatting to be applied TO COLUMN (B4-B71),(D4-D71),(F4-F71),(H4-H71),(J4-J71),(L4-L71),(N4-N71),(P4-P71),(R4-R71) WHICH SATISFY a CONDITION AS BELOW.
   Examplw, valid for H4 cell
   =$H$4=XLOOKUP($H$4;$U$13:$U$1146;$V$13:$V$1146)THEN CHANGE TO YELLOW COLOR.

tHERE WILL BE  NAMES IN THE EVERY CELL IN THE  ABOVE COLUMNS AND EVERY CELL WILL CHECK THE INFORMATION IN THE COLUMN (U13-U1146).För exampl, IF THE iNFORMATIONS in cell H4 matches with the information in u column then H4 will be highlighted. the same will be applied to all the cells for above mentioned column.

and the code will be valid for apx.31 sheets in the workbook, will contain same information and same kind of conditional formatting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Comment: You can get a start for your VBA by recording a macro while applying the conditional formatting manually.

Answer (score 0):

Below code creates a `public sub` that defines the conditional formatting rules.
Function `funcApplyContitionalFormatting` applies the specified rules from mentioned `Sub`.

```
Public Sub condFormat(ws as Worksheet, startCol as Long, startRow as Long, fRow As Long, formattingRule as String, interiorColor as Long, fontColor as Long)

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(startRow , startCol), ws.Cells(fRow, startCol))
    
    rng.FormatConditions.Delete
    rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        formatRule 
     
    rng.FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
              
    rng.FormatConditions(1).Font.Color = fontColor 
    rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = interiorColor 
  
End Sub
```

Here are the function that applies the formatting rule above (also using a table/listobject to get the final row with data in that table):

```
Public Function funcApplyConditionalFormatting()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects("yourTable")  
    fRow = lo.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Call functions
    condFormat(ws, 4, 3, fRow, "YourFormulaHere", 65535, 65535)

    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Function
```

You'd need to change inputs to suit your specific requirements, but this works for general formatting with VBA.